# Setting ID to identify type of Chip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have some Material UI "Chips" that contain text, which I reference. In my example, image, you can see that there are Chips for the White Advantages section and also the Black Advantages section. Sometimes these Chips contain the identical text, which is where my problem comes in.

If someone clicks a Chip, it looks at the text inside the Chip to determine what to do. But I also need it to check to see if they clicked the Chip in the White Advantages or Black Advantages section. Therefore, I figure I need to have some kind of identifier attached to that Chip. This is the part where I am stuck because I am not sure how!

Please note that these Chips are generated by using map on an array, with one map function for the White section and another for the Black section.

So, my question is, how do I attach something to each Chip to say it is in the White or Black category (without having to put White or Black in the text of the Chip itself)?

[image: Map generated list]

Comment: You can pass this variable in the `onClick` handler. E.g. `array.map(advantage => <Chip onClick={() => onChip(advantage.color) />`. If you want more accurate answer, please create a codesandbox.

Comment: That worked great thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in the end:

````
                     <li style={litags}>
                          <Chip
                            label={name1}
                            color="primary"
                            variant="outlined"
                            onMouseOver={event => {
                              highlightSquares(name1, 'White');
                            }}
                            onMouseLeave={event =>
                              board.current.removeMarkers(undefined, undefined)
                            }
                            onClick={event => {
                              popupInstruction(name1, 'White');
                            }}
                          />
                    </li>
                     ```
````